# SQL Update sibling record field from first in series

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a query that will take a value from a field, and update this in the sibling records.

For context, I have a sales table (salesID primary key) with child table (quote) that have a quoteID primary key and the sales ID foreign key. I wish to create a query that will select the salespersonname field from the child table for the first quote record, and update this field to all child records.

Is this possible?  I've tried the below with no luck.

```
update quotes
set salespersonname= x.salespersonname from 
(select salespersonname from quotes Inner Join sales on quotesalesID = salesID 
where quoteID = '1') as x
```

Example Data

```
Sales table
SalesID
1
2



Quote Table
QuoteID SalesID SalesPersonname
1 2 Jim
2 2 Sarah
4 1 Bob
3 2 Null
```

Expected outcome
    SalesID
    1
    2

```
Quote Table
QuoteID SalesID SalesPersonname
1 2 Jim
2 2 Jim
4 1 Bob
3 2 Jim
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current query ?

Comment: It doesn't update any rows but there is definitely data that exists where the sales person within the first quote record differs to the second quote record

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server, I've added some example data (apologies for the formatting, i'm fairly new to this site!)

Comment: why you are using "quoteID = salesID " ?? i guess quoteID is the primary key of the quote table... so thats the problem i guess

Comment: Sorry thats just a typo on here, it is joining on QuoteSalesID = SalesID

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Still not sure of the business logic but here is what I think you are trying to do:

The CTE will get the 'first' record for each SalesID.  Usually this would have some business logic like a date but I will use the lowest QuoteID.

Sample Data:

```
Create Table #Quotes (QuoteID Int, QuoteSalesID Int, SalesPersonName Varchar(100))

Insert #Quotes Values (1, 2, 'Jim')
Insert #Quotes Values (2, 2, 'Sarah')
Insert #Quotes Values (4, 1, 'Bob')
Insert #Quotes Values (3, 2, Null)

;
With cteGetLowestQuoteID AS
(
Select QuoteSalesID, SalesPersonName, 
       Row_Number() Over (Partition By QuoteSalesID Order By QuoteID) RowNum
    From #Quotes
)
Update Q Set Q.SalesPersonName = C.SalesPersonName
    From #Quotes Q
    Join cteGetLowestQuoteID C On C.QuoteSalesID = Q.QuoteSalesID
    Where C.RowNum = 1

Select * From #Quotes
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

Before Edit:

Your question does not really make sense to me.  On a side note salespersonname really does not belong on the quotes table and unless sales is your salesperson table it does not belong there either.

Here is how to best present sample data, in my opinion.  Code ready to run.

```
-- Drop Table #Sales Drop Table #Quotes
Create Table #Sales (SalesID Int, SalesPersonName Varchar(100))
Create Table #Quotes (QuoteID Int, QuoteSalesID Int, SalesPersonName Varchar(100))

Insert #Sales Values (1, 'John')
Insert #Sales Values (2, 'Joe')

Insert #Quotes Values (1, 2, 'Jim')
Insert #Quotes Values (2, 2, 'Sarah')
Insert #Quotes Values (3, 2, Null)

Select * 
    From #Sales S
    Join #Quotes Q On Q.QuoteSalesID = S.SalesID
```

This provides:

```
SalesID SalesPersonName QuoteID QuoteSalesID    SalesPersonName
2   Joe 1   2   Jim
2   Joe 2   2   Sarah
2   Joe 3   2   NULL
```

You say you want the records to be updated to Jim, and that is where I am confused. I am guessing that you want to update the quotes records to have Joe as the sales person name based on the foreign key of 2.  If I am mistaken the queries here should help you get to what you need.

I fixed a few typos in your query and ran this:

```
Update #Quotes 
    Set SalesPersonName= x.salespersonname 
    From 
        (Select Q.Salespersonname 
            From #Quotes Q 
            Inner Join #Sales S On QuoteSalesID = SalesID 
            Where QuoteID = '1') As x 

Select * 
    From #Sales S
    Join #Quotes Q On Q.QuoteSalesID = S.SalesID
```

This produced:

```
SalesID SalesPersonName QuoteID QuoteSalesID    SalesPersonName
2   Joe 1   2   Jim
2   Joe 2   2   Jim
2   Joe 3   2   Jim
```

This is Jim not Joe.  Again this is why I am confused, your query works for your stated goal even though I do not understand the business logic behind it.  I have never seen an update used in the way you have.  Here is how I would write it:

```
Update Q
    Set Q.SalesPersonName= S.salespersonname 
    From #Quotes Q
    Inner Join #Sales S On QuoteSalesID = SalesID 

Select * 
    From #Sales S
    Join #Quotes Q On Q.QuoteSalesID = S.SalesID
```

This updates the name to Joe on all three records.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it is not possible to change the structure of the tables in order to come to the desired out come. I Just to change the quote table using the following logic.

Comment: Accidentally hit the button then!

Comment: The sales table has multiple child tables (quotes). I need the query to select the value within the salesperson field, from the first child record for the specific sales record and use this value to update each salesperson field in all subsequent child (quote records). Hope this is a bit clearer

Comment: This is still a bit confusing.  Can you edit your question to have sample data as I have in my answer and also what the date produced should look like?

Comment: I have added the example now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understood your question correctly but based on your query I''l suggest you the following query:

```
UPDATE
    Q
SET
    salespersonname = x.salespersonname
FROM
    quotes Q
INNER JOIN sales x
    ON quotesalesID = salesID
WHERE
    quoteID = '1';
```

Comment: I've had a look at this but as the sales table doesn't contain the salespersonname unfortunately this wouldn't work

Comment: Do you want to update the quotes with the salesperson which did the quote matching the provided quoteId?

Comment: this would be :
`UPDATE
    Q
SET
    salespersonname = Q2.salespersonname
FROM
    quotes Q
INNER JOIN quotes Q2
    ON Q.SalesId = Q2.salesID
       AND Q2.quoteID = '1';`